# Angular Agm/core map not working with observable using async to show map and dynamically add markers

Tags: angular, google-maps, asynchronous, observable, google-maps-markers

I call an API to return an observable with a list of map markers. I am trying to use a standard `ngIf async` logic on the map to display the map when the observable receives data. When It does return a list of map marker data I try to iterate over `agm-marker` to dynamically generate the markers on the map as shown below:

```
<agm-map *ngIf='ObservableListItems | async as listItems'
  [latitude]="lat" 
  [longitude]="lng">

  <agm-marker *ngFor='let items of listItems'
    [latitude]="items .latitude" 
    [longitude]="items .longitude"
    [iconUrl]="image'
    [title]="items.title"
    [label]="items.label"
    class="agm-marker">
  </agm-marker>
</agm-map>
```

Now I know this kind of logic should work as I tested with simple divs as shown below:

```
<div *ngIf='ObservableListItems| async as listItems'>
  <div *ngFor='let items of listItems'>
    <h1>{{items.latitude}}</h1>
    <h1>{{items.longitude}}</h1>
    <h1>{{items.title}}</h1>
    <h1>{{items.label}}</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried for a bit but seem unable to get this to work for the `agm map` and `agm-marker`. I tried using `ng-content` and `ng-container` with it however still it seems not to work. The interesting part is that there is no console error at all, just the map not being rendered.

There are a few reasons why I would like to use an observable.

1. Less code to write
2. Not having to manage a subscription
3. I would like to add `else loading` to show a css loading skeleton until the data is returned for perceived performance

My Components TS file shows you where some variables are coming from:

```
export class MapComponent {

  lat: number = 51.678418;
  lng: number = 7.809007;

  /* 
     These were used in the map but I removed as I do 
     not have anything to open yet. Hopefully not required
  */
  // markerClickable: boolean = true;
  // openInfoWindow: boolean = true;

  /* Custom marker icon for the map */
  image = {
    url: './assets/marker.png',
    scaledSize: {
      width: 60,
      height: 60
    }
  }

  constructor(private _MapService: MapService) { 

  }

  public get ObservableListMap(): Observable<Array<ListItemMap>> {
    return this._MapService.ObservableListMap;
  }
}
```

Comment: I have run into the same issue. It seems that the only fix is to manually unwrap the observable in typescript.